# Raspberry Pi Business use VS Personal use

Tags: hardware

I am new with Raspberry Pi... Since I wanted to buy one piece of raspberry pi, on the website I found ([RS online](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi)) that there are 2 possibilities:

- Buy your RPi 3 model for business use
- Buy your RPi 3 model for personal use

I would like to know what is the difference?

I am doing one project, and at first I want to use it personally as a server for my app, but I don't know now if I will make some $ with it or not.....

As I understood the boards are same, the RPi for business and personal are the same boards, so I am confused....

Is there some licensing stuff then going on, or some restrictions?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you please name the vendor you've checked? Maybe that helps in *guessing* some answers.

Comment: Hi!, yea sure. here is the link -> http://uk.rs-online.com/web/generalDisplay.html?id=raspberrypi

Comment: As you can see, there are 2 options... I really don't know what is the difference... and as I mentioned., I don't know what will be with this project, if I will make some $ or not in the future ...

Comment: Click both and you will learn ;)

Comment: The thing is that RS will sell only to business customers. If you click home use, you'll get a direction to other resellers.

Comment: Farnell do the same but it's a bit more obvious: they've got a subsidiary called CPC with handles consumer stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The thing is that RS will sell only to business customers. If you click home use, you'll get a direction to other resellers that sell to consumers too. Unless you convince RS that you are a business customer (providing a VAT number) there'll be no deal.

> RS's authorised resellers for Raspberry Pi
>
> The below companies are selected by RS Components as authorised resellers for Raspberry Pi products.
>
> Consumer customers, those without VAT numbers, are requested to purchase via the below listed resellers.

That's also part of RS' general *Terms & Conditions of Sale*:

> RS is a business-to-business supplier. The RS website is intended for use by business customers and not by consumers or private individuals.

Comment: Tnx! one more question. So there is no restriction on how I will use this hardware, or if I will have some economic income or not?

Comment: At least not that I know of (but I am no lawyer). But it's worth pointing out that the Pi's primary use case is educational so check thoroughly if it meets your business needs.

Comment: I mean before I buy servers for the business needs, I wanted to know it it works or not.... with this solution I can check without the need to spend much money...

Comment: You can buy from RS as an individual if you want. Nothing stopping you from registering, and buying what you like. You don't need to provide a VAT number, or anything else to prove you are a business. Note the prices on RS exclude VAT, so you will need to add that on.

Comment: It is not about legal/licensing and more about RS's choice of distribution. They don't want to be dealing with a vast amount of single purchase orders/claims and are more interested in dealing with bulk purchases. If you click business you will notice pricing for multiple lots listed and discounts as as the lot numbers add up. Businesses that buy in bulk or are repeat purchasers are their target customer. As @vclaw mentioned they will still possibly sale to you, but you are not their target customer. Don't expect consumer level customer service as well.

Comment: @vclaw and BradMetcalf, while it *might be* that they do sell to individuals it's still explicitly stated in their *Terms and Conditions of Sale* that they do B2B. So I would not be surprised if the just don't. After all consumer customers have additional rights that B2B does not and they're thus typically more of a hassle.